# what happens when there are ambiguous attributes in android layout xml?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have this layout xml

does order matter?

I mean what will be the padding?

what would happen if the same attribute repeat twice? compilation error?

4,4,4,0
or 4,4,4,4

or non deterministic?

Comment: I think you missed the file

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I completely miss understood your question in my previous answer and made a mistake myself.

I'm not sure where you can find this in the android docs, but from my own experience you cannot provide the same attribute twice (this would lead to a compilation error).

To update my previous answer (I've edited this post to get rid of it, so I don't confuse or mislead any one), with the padding example I gave, padding overrides padding-top no matter what order you put them in.

Also I'm sorry for the slow response, I've been away for a few weeks and only just got back. I hope you found a better answer before I updated this post and I'll be quicker to clarify anything if you want me to.

Comment: `will display the same as` - so both will show what paddings?
60, 500, 60, 60?

where is it written in the refered android doc? couldn't find again

Comment: Sorry, I completely miss understood your question, I've updated it now and hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As for already existing attribute, you cant use the same attribute more than once in the same XML tag.
If you do try to use the same attribute twice you will get  “duplicate attribute” XML error.